# Unmet Dependencies mongodb-org-server: Depends libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2)

Tags: package-management, dependencies, mongodb

I was trying to install R-base but I'm facing unmet dependencies.

I have tried all possible ways to uninstall and install, re-run mongodb services... but nothing worked.

The installation shows an error. Uninstallation doesn't work. This is the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have tried many solutions from Stack Overflow, but nothing works.

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu and what verson of MongoDB server are you trying to install? I recommend following the official instructions to [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system). Make sure you choose the correct package for your Ubuntu release, as some of the dependencies are different. Also note that only Ubuntu LTS (Long Term Support) releases are supported, so for MongoDB 4.0 you should be running either Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) or Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).

Comment: I was using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Latest version of MongoDB .. i tried every possible way to solve that but nothing help . i tried help from StackOverflow also.. Now i Installed ubuntu 19.04 and its working .